# How to change the title from bibliography to References

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, section-titles

I am using the Bibtex file to generate my references in my thesis. my thesis class is `{report}` and using the command `\bibliographystyle{refsort}` and `\bibliography{thesisreferences}` to generate my references but the title of the page comes out to be "bibliography". I want to change it to "References". How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. When using the `report` document class, the macro`\bibname` determines what gets output as the header of the bibliography. In the `report` document class, the default value of this macro is, as you've discovered, `Bibliography`. To get `References` instead, simply insert the instruction `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` in the preamble.